# "be used" v. "get used"

Tags: word-difference, past-habitual, used-to

> I **was used** to working long hours.
>
> I **got used** to working long hours.

What meaning do the verbs **be** and **get** have here? My textbook doesn't explain it. But from the examples they're used in, I have an impression that **get** emphasizes that there is some *transition* between one state and another. For example in my sentence **got used** means that I *was not used* to it before but then *became used* to it. While **was used** doesn't imply that, maybe I was *always* used to it.

And this usage in Present Simple:

> I am used to it.
>
> I get used to it.

Does **get** imply that however I *am not* used to it at the moment but I *will be* used to it soon?

Comment: To understand the difference between "be used to" and "get used to", just think of "get used to" as "become used to". However, I found the sentence "I get used to it", as a standalone sentence, rather odd. To me, it would be more natural to say "I'm getting used to it", or say it as a command "You get used to it", or say it as "I can/could/might/would/will get used to it", or put it in some conditions such as "I will keep doing it until I get used to it".

Comment: @DamkerngT, I agree with everything you said there, except the classification of "You get used to it" as a command; with the word "You" at the front, it's just a statement of fact:  "How can you stand living like this??" she cried.  "Eh," he said, "you get used to it."  (Without the leading 'you', it is properly an imperative:  "I don't like going to school!" whined the child.  "Get used to it," said the parent, "you'll be doing it every day for the next 10 years.")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Think this way - "Why don't you practice the prayanama?"; "Ah, no. it's too tough."; "That's initially. Once you practice it daily, you'll **get used** to it." Certainly, you are *not used to it* now but then after some practice, you *will be* used to it.

In this case of working for long hours that requires more endurance...

You were used to .... -> you find no difficulty doing that and it was a kind of regular practice (habit?).

You got used to .... -> you found it difficult at first but then with practice, you found it okay and not so difficult.

You got it right! Got describes some transition there.

Check out [here (11th point)](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/get#get__4):

> got (linking verb) - to reach a particular state or condition; to make somebody/something/yourself reach a particular state or condition. As in *You'll soon get used to the climate here.*

Whereas *be* describes the state you are already in.

Comment: You still haven't explained the subtleties between *be* and *get* in this structure.

Comment: @Graduate check with link. edited.

Answer (score 1):

You question is about two steps

> 1) getting used to *something*
>   2) being used to *something*

You can think of it this way

> first one must "get used to *something*", before one can "be used to *something*".
>
> Once you **get used** to waking up at 6am, you will soon **be used** to commuting to work.

If you **got used** to *something*, then you **were used** to it.

> I finally **got used** to my new schedule, and **was used** to the chaos.
>
> Eventhough I **was used to** the long hours of studying, I never **got used to** the intensity of exams.

"Being used to *something*" does not necessarily mean it was easy to "get used to" it.
Sometimes the "being used to" is easier than the "getting used to".