# be used to VS get used to in Future time

Tags: phrasal-verbs, future-tense, used-to

I've read this [one](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/213921/will-have-to-get-used-to-be-used-to) and I still haven't got the difference. Could anyone explain the difference on these two examples:

1. There are some things in this life that you'll never ***be used
   to*** / ***get used to***.
2. I don't think I'll ever ***be used to*** / ***get used to*** driving on the
   left. It’s so strange!

Are they both grammatically correct but with different meaning ? My thought is they are with the next difference:

1. "will never be used to" states that I will not be accustomed to something and DOESN'T mention if I would ever take an attempt to. ***--> less informative***
2. "will never get used to" states that I will not be accustomed to something and implies that I would at least try to get accustomed to that something. ***--> more informative***

Although my grammar test I've passed states that only options with "get" are grammatically correct.

Comment: Both are grammatically correct. If you _are used to_ something, it feels normal and familiar to you. If it was unfamiliar at some time in the past, you have had to _get (become) used to it_. Both your example sentences are about becoming used to something, so _get used to_ is the most likely choice.

Comment: See https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/17450/be-used-v-get-used?rq=1

Comment: @KateBunting Okay, Thank you! But I don't see any signs of 'becoming', that's my problem. Another example: "I graduated from architectural college. I will never be a doctor." OR  "I graduated from architectural college. I will never become a doctor." First sentence defines second. In the first we made one dry fact about graduating from college. We aren't talking about whether I have a desire/dream/plan/intention to become a doctor or not. We don't know. Only thing we know I will not be a doctor at all, so why I'm supposed to use 'become/get' ?)

Comment: I wouldn't use _become a doctor_ unless I was talking about someone who is trying unsuccessfully to study medicine. But you _get used to_ a new way of life (gradually accustom yourself to it), and you _get better_ from an illness. Your problem seems to be with the negative use - I think you just have to accept that, in English, we say _will never get used to_ and not _will never be used to_.